# Value error converting a string to int in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that takes a string, which represents a date, from a list and compares it to another two dates. If it's between those two dates, the program replaces the string in the list with the day, month and year separated.

The problem is that if I convert that string to an 'int', in the console it's okay, but when I run the program I have the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

That is my code:

```
def date(lst, d1, d2):
for d in lst:
    if int(d[4:])>=int(d1[4:]) or int(d[4:])<=int(d2[4:]):
        if int(d[2:4])>=int(d1[2:4]) or int(d[2:4])<=int(d2[2:4]):
            if int(d[0:2])>=int(d1[0:2]) or int(d[0:2])<=int(d2[0:2]):
                j=d
                j1=j[0:2]
                j2=j[2:4]
                j3=j[4:]
                lst.insert(lst.index(d),j3)
                lst.insert(lst.index(d),j2)
                lst.insert(lst.index(d),j1)
                lst.remove(d)
return lst
```

So,

```
print date(['24012014', '22032015', '03022015', '15122014', '11112015'], '22022014', '10112015')
```

should return `['24012014', 22, 3, 2015, 3, 2, 2015, 15, 12, 2014, '11112015']`

Comment: Yikes - don't change the list while you try to walk through it. Make a new list and return that.

Comment: I would,but that's for school and i have to use the same list....

Comment: if the dates were in the opposite order, e.g. `20141225`, you could compare them without converting them to `int`

Comment: Is `datetime` an option?

Comment: I can use only only standard modules...

Comment: The [`datetime` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) *is* a standard module

Comment: Still,the prof said I can't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out these two lines, and it will work:

```
lst.insert(lst.index(d), j2)

lst.insert(lst.index(d), j1)
```

Apparently, when you loop through the list and at the same
time remove, and insert in the start indexing gets wrong.

To avoid trouble, work with a copy of the list:

```
def date(lst, d1, d2):
    lstC = list(lst)
    for d,dd in  zip(lst, lstC):
        if int(d[4:]) >= int(d1[4:]) or int(d[4:]) <= int(d2[4:]):
            if int(d[2:4]) >= int(d1[2:4]) or int(d[2:4]) <= int(d2[2:4]):
                if int(d[0:2]) >= int(d1[0:2]) or int(d[0:2]) <= int(d2[0:2]):
                    j = d
                    j1 = j[0:2]
                    j2 = j[2:4]
                    j3 = j[4:]
                    ind_d = lst.index(d)
                    lstC.insert(ind_d, j3)
                    lstC.insert(ind_d, j2)
                    lstC.insert(ind_d, j1)
                    lstC.remove(dd)

    return lstC

print(date(['24012014', '22032015', '03022015', '15122014', '11112015'], '22022014', '10112015'))

['24', '22', '02', '2015', '03', '2015', '2014', '22032015', '03022015', '15122014', '11112015']
```

you can avoid indexing errors if you start looping from end. But you need
to change the logic of your script obviosly.

```
def date(lst, d1, d2):
    # from copy import deepcopy
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1, -1, -1):
        if int(lst[i][4:])>=int(d1[4:]) or int(lst[i][4:])<=int(d2[4:]):
            if int(lst[i][2:4])>=int(d1[2:4]) or int(lst[i][2:4])<=int(d2[2:4]):
                if int(lst[i][0:2])>=int(d1[0:2]) or int(lst[i][0:2])<=int(d2[0:2]):
                    j=lst[i]
                    j1=j[0:2]
                    j2=j[2:4]
                    j3=j[4:]
                    ind_d = lst.index(lst[i])
                    lst.insert(ind_d,j3)
                    lst.insert(ind_d,j2)
                    lst.insert(ind_d,j1)
                    lst.remove(lst[i])

    return lst

print(date(['24012014', '22032015', '03022015', '15122014', '11112015'], '22022014', '10112015'))

['01', '2014', '24012014', '03', '2015', '22032015', '02', '2015', '03022015', '15122014', '11112015']
```

Comment: What's that line for: for d,dd in  zip(lst,lstC):?

Comment: it does zip together these two lists, so that iterating at the same time is possible. It is a standard and very useful operation in Python.